# IAsyncOperation returning pointer or reference to Winrt type

Tags: c++-winrt

1. Can i only use IAsyncOperation with value types only and no pointer or reference IAsyncOperation IAsyncOperation.

Basically Async function returning value by reference or pointer, How to.

```
Fail
IAsyncOperation<Buffer*> GetBufferAsync()
    {
        co_await 1500ms;
        return  mvo_buffer;

    }

Fail
IAsyncOperation<Buffer&> GetBufferAsync()
    {
        co_await 1500ms;
        return  mvo_buffer;

    }

Pass
Buffer* GetBuffer()
    {
        return &mvo_buffer;
    }

Pass
IAsyncOperation<Buffer> GetBufferAsync()
    {
        co_await 1500ms;
        return  mvo_buffer;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for quick update. Where can i get info about performance characteristics of copying projected type by value. For example  how much of this work takes place across ABI and the performance there.  In terms of how it differs from standard C++ copy by value. Also  i assume after copy there will be separate objects behind projected type in ABI.

Comment: Most WinRT types are represented by COM interface pointers on the ABI. So a C++ copy amounts to an AddRef on the interface pointer, thus it is relatively cheap. After the copy, both WinRT types in C++/WinRT point to the same implementation in memory.

Comment: Copy A to B, Does that mean any subsequent changes to A also happen to B. Leads me to question the role of pointers for runtime objects. Seems pointer to and by value have same effect.  So only way to achieve true copy in Winrt is to construct  new object with same values as the other. Does this mean c++ pointers are usless for winrt types, just like C# reference types. Thanks

Comment: WinRT objects are only copyable if the object provides some explicit "Copy" method. There is no intrinsic or pervasive copy semantic as there is in other type systems. In some sense, a WinRT object in C++/WinRT is thus similar to a C# reference type.

Comment: Fantastic thanks for taking time to clear explain that, cheers

Answer (score 1):

The type of a WinRT `IAsyncOperation` must be a WinRT type (without qualifiers). Assuming `Buffer`, in your example, is a WinRT type then the only acceptable form is `IAsyncOperation<Buffer>`.